# Saving image to file with php

Tags: php, upload

I try to upload an image name to MySQL and the image to a specific file.

Those are my variables:

```
$Image=$_FILES['image']["name"];
$Target="upload/".basename($FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

My form group works fine so I see the image name without any problem:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="imageselect"><span class="fieldinfo"> Select Image: </span></label>
   <input type="File" class="form-control" name="image" id="imageselect">
   </div>
```

The file also comes to temporary file. 
I understand that from this debug code, I get "WORKS!":

```
  if(!file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][0])){
     $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]= "Try Again.";
         redirect_to("addnewpost.php");
}else{ $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]= "WORKS!";
         redirect_to("addnewpost.php");  
}
```

However when I test if it arrives to "upload file" then it I get error:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],$Target)){
     $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"]= "Success";
      redirect_to("addnewpost.php");


} else {

    $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]= "Does not upload to file";
     redirect_to("addnewpost.php");

}
```

I tried to search if the problem was about permissions in Mac but also could not find any solution.

Comment: `$_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = $_FILES["image"]["error"];` Would you check if there is an error using the code?

Comment: if i saw one of my interns write a line like this 
$_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]
they would be fired. in no case or scenario is it wise or beneficial to save error information in a session.  i strongly suggest you read the entire section on php sessions http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Solved: For MAC: Go to the file > Right click > Get info > and then change all the permissions to read&write .

Answer (score 0):

You should to try this option. Thanks you.

$Target = "upload/".$_FILES["image"]["name"];

Comment: For MAC: Go to the folder > Right click > Get info > and then change all the permissions to read&write